# Issue while POST restful service request in WSO2 API1.7

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

It worked well earlier, but now the same docs I followed to send another restful service as a POST method and it is throwing the below error

```
ERROR - SequenceMediator Error while building message
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:236)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:111)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:68)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:64)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleRequest(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:285)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:83)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:64)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:344)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:385)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to convert JSON to XML payload. Expected a ',' or '}' at character 26 of { "xmlPayload" : username=sm&password=sm10&versions=1&regid=1&deviceType=1}
    at org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBuilder.processDocument(JSONBuilder.java:87)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:118)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:107)
    ... 19 more
[2016-04-04 11:35:45,158]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error while building message
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in APIM 1.7 where it adds an extra `xmlPayload` element for multi-rooted JSON messages. This is due to a bug in Jettison library which is the default json message parser in APIM 1.7. You can eliminate this error by changing the message builder and formatter by modifying `axis2.xml` file as follows;

Add the following builder and formatter in `axis2.xml` in APIM 1.7 for `application/json` type (comment out the existing message builder and formatter for "application/json" type)

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                  class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>


<messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
```

Comment: I made the above changes and i now get this error `HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'username' is not present`

Comment: Have you commented out the existing `messageFormatter` and `messageBuilder` entries in that file?

Comment: Yes.                                                                                     `<!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"                          class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/-->
 <messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamFormatter"/><!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBuilder"/-->
 <messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamBuilder"/>`

Comment: We have released API Manager 1.10. Can you try on that?

Comment: Is it available for Linux 64bit OS as I could not find it at http://wso2.com/api-management/try-it/  or at  http://wso2.com/more-downloads/api-manager/

Comment: Yes, It's compatible with Linux 64 bit. Don't you see Download button there?  You are on the correct page.

Comment: With my requirement I have moved to use WSO2 App Manager now, since I need to provide the user an interactive window for the application.